# A notion of restricted injectivity for Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I apologize in advance if this is well-known.

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let's call only for this post that $X$ is *self-injective* if for every closed subspaces
\begin{equation}
A\subseteq B\subseteq X  \tag{*}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
and bounded linear $T:A\to X$, there exists an extension $\widetilde{T}:B\to X$. The difference from the definition of injectivity is the restriction \eqref{eq:1} that $A$, $B$ must be subspaces of $X$. We can define $\lambda$-self-injectivity similarly.

Clearly, injective and separably injective Banach spaces are self-injective in this sense.

> **Question:** Are there other self-injective (especially $1$-self-injective) Banach spaces? Is there a characterization of self-injectivity?

---

**edit/update:** Thanks to Jesus Castillo's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452642/a-notion-of-restricted-injectivity-for-banach-spaces#comment1170763_452668), the common terminology for these spaces is *extensible*. If I'm allowed, I'd like to be a voluntary advertiser of a group of interesting problems, which I'm eager to learn the answers. The snippet below is from the copy of [the book (p.331-332)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3gaoEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA331) on books.google.com co-authored by Jesus Castillo.

[image]

Comment: Every   $ X$ which is a $\mathcal L_\infty$ space satisfying the property, for every  closed subspace $A$ and every $ T : A \to X $ a bounded operator $T$ is of the form $ {\lambda}I_{A,X} + K$ with $K :A \to X$ a compact operator, is $\lambda$ - self injective. Argyros Haydon space does not satisfy the property and I do not know any such space.

  The result follows from a classical result of J. Lindenstrauss that asserts that $ {\mathcal L}_\infty $ spaces are $\lambda $ - injective for compact operators.

Comment: As has been pointed out in a deleted answer: you can remove $B$ from the definition, i.e. $X$ is self-injective if and only if every bounded linear map $T:A \to X$ where $A \subseteq X$ is a closed subspace extends with the same norm to a bounded linear map on all of $X$.

Comment: @SArgyros : Professor Argyros, it is my honor to receive a comment from the co-creator of one of the marvels & artworks of the Banach space theory. The property you've cited, combined with the compact extension property, must give self-injectivity. I'm deadly curious, but I'm not at the level to see why or why not $X_{AH}$ is self-injective. I'd be grateful if you guide.

Comment: @YemonChoi the deleted answer isn't available to me. Thank you for pointing out that $B$ can be replaced by $X$. My purpose was to emphasize the analogy with injectivity at the first look.

Comment: @YemonChoi : The definition didn't require the extension to have the same norm in order not to inadvertently lose anything interesting. I made up the name 1-self-injective instead.

Comment: @Onur Oktay: The Argyros Haydon example does not satisfy the property. I pointed out in my comment , stated above, and I also deleted my answer.

Comment: @SArgyros : Professor Argyros, my apologies. Ευχαριστώ

Comment: @Onur Oktay:The Argyros Haydon space has closed subspaces $A$ and $S:A \to A$ bounded strictly singular and non compact. Clearly this operator $S$ is not extended  to an operator to the whole space since such an extension must be a compact one.

Comment: I did not check details, but I think known results and arguments show that a super reflexive space that is self injective must have, for every $\epsilon>0$, type $2-\epsilon$ and cotype $2+\epsilon$. This suggests looking at the $2$-convexification of the Tsirelson space.

Comment: @BillJohnson : Professor Johnson, thank you for your comment. I believe anything a legend in Banach space theory like yourself says; however, I cannot see how I can prove this statement. Could you either refer me to the known results or put down a few details?

Comment: @SArgyros : Professor Argyros, thank you for your guidance. At the moment I should do my homework, perhaps find examples of these subspaces $A\subset X_{AH}$ in your published work, rather than asking menial details. Thank you very much again.

Comment: The criterion is that if $X$ contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $Y$ and also an uncomplemented subspace isomorphic isomorphic to $Y$, then $X$ is not self injective. Localize that to if $X$ contains uniformly complemented $\ell_p^n$'s and also non  uniformly complemented $\ell_p^n$'s, then $X$ is not self injective (use the argument of Davis-Dean-Singer from the 1960's for this). What you really need is the degree of complementation of one sequence of  $\ell_p^n$'s is asymptotically different from that of another sequence of  $\ell_p^n$'s....

Comment: .... I think you can theorem quote to show that exists in all super reflexive spaces; maybe even in all spaces with non trivial type (Pisier duality theorem for spaces with non trivial type).

Comment: @BillJohnson : Professor Johnson, you made it crystal clear, even for an amateur(=me). Thank you for your detailed comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those spaces have been called extensible (and its variations UFO, automorphic) in papers of Moreno-Plichko [On automorphic Banach spaces, Israel J. Math. 169 (2009) 29-45; or Castillo-Ferenczi-Moreno [On Uniformly Finitely Extensible Banach spaces, J.M.A.A. 410 (2014) 670-686] and others. For instance $c_0(I)$ is extensible.

Comment: Probably the best reference is Chapter 7 in "Homological Methods in Banach Spaces", Cambridge Studies in Advanced Math . 203 by Cabello Sánchez and Castillo.

Comment: +1 This is amazing, thank you very much for the exact terminology and the references.

Comment: In particular, Theorem 7.2.10 in Jesus' book with Cabello Sanchez proves something stronger than what I mentioned in my other comment. (Sorry about that, Jesus. I forgot what you et al did.)